# How to edit a contact in the "Contacts" app using LG G3

Tags: contacts, lg-g3

I use the Contacts app with this icon

[image: Contacts app icon]

and write something in the search field to find a contact.

I click the contacts name and come to this screen:
[image: contact screen]

Now, I have found no way to edit the phone number.
Clicking inside the box with the green caller will call the contact.

Clicking the menu will give me the menu alternatives: Delete, Join, Add to Home screen.

There is no text anywhere that sais "edit contact" or the like.

Clicking the contacts name will not result in anything.
Clicking the contacts photo will show it bigger.

Long clicking inside the box with green caller will popup a menu with the alternatives "Forward contact" and "Copy to clipboard".

Comment: That's not their real phone number is it? Maybe remove that!

Comment: I have altered the image to not reveal the phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the contact is synced to your contacts via online account (Facebook in this case). You are not allowed to edit that contact that is why there is no option of editing it. Get it!

Comment: The phone number is not from facebook.

Comment: Is this the only contact you are facing problem? Normally 'edit' icon would be beside 'menu(3 dots)' icon.

Comment: Some contacts have the pencil, some not, it seems. I never thought about checking more contacts, for some reason.

Comment: I'm not getting whats wrong exactly because I never had that problem in any Android phone (LG, Samsung, Sony). I'll look around for solution.

Comment: The problem is that the pencil is not always there. If you find a solution, let me know!

Comment: You can actually test if this is the the reason. Open facebook and tell it not to sync your contacts. if this contact is not there, or you can now "edit", it is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found the answer you are looking for but I found if you click the join button in the edit menu you can combine two contacts into one. So all you need to do is make a contact for the person with their number or what have you and then join it with the facebook contact listing.

Comment: No, I did not really find an answer. Joining is of course possible, but why is it needed?

Answer (score -1):

Long press the contact and then the edit button will show up !